# Unexpected behaviour when setSortingEnabled(1) is called

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidget

I have a `QTableWidget` with first column populated with checkable items, so I needed to overload those items to be able to sort them. Sorting works as expected when I click on header of that column (rows are sorted - first there are checked rows and then not checked).

The problem occurs when I run my GUI and do not click on header of any column to sort table and then do this:

```
tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(0); 
// check/uncheck some checkable items here
tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(1);
```

In that situation overridden `__lt__` is called 100+ times, but I do not expect that because I didn't clicked on header of that column to sort. So, why `__lt__` is called? Why it compares some checkable items even if I didn't clicked on header of that column to sort them?

Please help me, calling `__lt__` consumes too much time when I have 30+ rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From docs (C++ qt but applies):

> sortingEnabled : bool
>
> This property holds whether sorting is enabled.
>
> If this property is true, sorting is enabled for the table. If this
>   property is false, sorting is not enabled. The default value is false.
>
> Note:. **Setting the property to true with setSortingEnabled()
>   immediately triggers a call to sortByColumn()** with the current sort
>   section and order.

And if you check docs of QHeaderView (which is queried by the widget to know the column to sort by) you can read:

> int QHeaderView::sortIndicatorSection () const
>
> Returns the logical index of the section that has a sort indicator. By
>   default this is **section 0**.
>
> See also setSortIndicator(), sortIndicatorOrder(), and
>   setSortIndicatorShown().

And:

> Qt::SortOrder QHeaderView::sortIndicatorOrder () const
>
> Returns the order for the sort indicator. If no section has a sort
>   indicator the return value of this function is **undefined**.

So you should be careful with this

Comment: Thanks for your answer. First of all, I've already tried `sortIndicatorSection()` before and after `setSortingEnable(1)`, both results were "7". I have 7 columns (0-6), so I guessed that default sorted section is not 0 but column out of table (section 7 in my case) although sorting behaves like it is 0. Maybe that is because I have tableWidget and not tableView?

Comment: Anyway, your answer pointed me in right direction and I've found this: `void QHeaderView::setSortIndicator(int logicalIndex, Qt::SortOrder order)` - _"logicalIndex may be -1, in which case no sort indicator will be shown and the model will return to its natural, unsorted order."_ .
This works for tableWidget also, putting that line before tableWidget is populated solved my problem.

Comment: QTableWidget inherits from QTableView. But handles a model internally. Strange that 7 returned. glad to help anyways :)

Comment: I have one more related question, so if you have any idea, please suggest it: I have this `self.connect(self.tableWidget,SIGNAL("cellChanged(int, int)"), self.DoSomething)`, so when I check/uncheck item `DoSomething` is called where I disable sorting, do some calculations and then enable sorting again.  Every time I check or uncheck any item, setSortingEnabled(1) consume more and more time, and I don't know how to follow up what is happening. (for example 0.031999 0.041 0.04799 0.05299 .....)